# Oracle Leading zero for number

Tags: oracle, decimal, zero

How can I disable removing leading zero for decimal, when it convert to char?

For example:

```
select to_char(0.1) from dual;
```

return .1, not 0.1.

I know than i can use format parameter, but i want that it work correct for implicit conversion.

I have a lot of plsql code for get data from database.
In some case there are conversions from float to varchar2.

For example use **dbms_sql.define_array** with **varchar2** table when column type of request is **number**.

I can try find all such things and correct them (and I do it), but IMHO it is better way to set up rule for such conversions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you explain what you mean by "i want that it work correct for implicit conversion"

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you cannot alter the default format for implicit conversion.

In case you limit yourself  to using the conversion in the context of inserts/updates to a given table, you might mimic the intended behaviour using [database triggers](http://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/database-triggers-overview.php). I do not see any advantage compared to an express format model in your queries for that use case.

There are some official oracle docs claiming that you can override built-in functions by re-implementing them in java. I have never done that, I do not know whether this is a generally viable method, and I would **strongly discourage** any attempt at tinkering with the database API (therefore, nolink is included) !

Assuming that what you aim at is feasible somehow, reconsider why you do not want to expressly indicate the conversion format. The few additional keystrokes are hardly a nuisance for the developer while the idiom  contributes to a self-documenting code base.

Spend your development resources more wisely than performing micro-optimizations !